# Objective-c Can't use IF statement

Tags: objective-c

I have the current code:

```
if ([fetchedObjects count] == 0){
    Timetable *info = nil;
} else {
    Timetable *info = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}
// Return Data
return info;
```

Inside a method in one of my classes. This code should run but xcode gives me the errors:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'info'
```

for the return info and

```
Unused variable 'info'
```

for the Timetable *info parts.

I have no clue why this is happening and the app does crash if I try to run it due to this. If i were to set the timtable without the if statement like this, it would work:

```
Timetable *info = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You are returning an object called info that the compiler does not know exists, as it is declared inside your if statement and not outside it.

Comment: @Luke Yeah I though that if it was always going to be declared no matter what, it would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring `info` variables in two different places, inside the `if` or `else`. `info` is not visible outside of the block. (This is basic C language stuff.)

This reads a little better:

```
Timetable* info = nil;
if ([fetchedObjects count] > 0)
{
   info = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}
return info;
```

Answer (score 2):

The scope of the variable `Timetable *info` is only within the `if(){}else{}` blocks. You'll need to declare it outside of the if statement if you want to return it later.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `info` is **only** the if statement. Declare it outside of it so it can be seen outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you define the info in the local scope inside the if..else.. block.

```
Timetable *info = nil;
if ([fetchedObjects count] != 0){
  info = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}

return info;
```

Do this instead